# Get GPS accuracy

Tags: gps, embedded, nmea

I am working with a SIM868 cellular modem with GPS capabilities. I have access to send and receive data from/to the GPS processor, a MediaTek MT2503DV.

When I look at the raw data coming out of the processor, I see numerous NMEA  strings ($GPGGA, $GPRMC...), and also $GPACCURACY. I cant find any documentation on $GPACCURACY, but I presume it is a number in meters of the accuracy of the GPS.
The $GPACCURACY string looks like this `$GPACCURACY,25.9*36`

1. What is $GPACCURACY, and what do the numbers following it mean?
2. Is there a way to only receive this and $RMC data out of the GPS?

Comment: Standard NMEA 0183 sentences have a two character _talker ID_ and a three character _format_specifier_, e,g, `$GPRMC,...`, one exception is proprietary sentences that star `P` followed by a three character _manufacturer ID_, e.g. `$PUBX,...`.  The sentences you describe do not conform to this standard, so are entirely proprietary; are you sure the GGA and RMC have no talker ID?   There is no standard sentence for configuring the sentences output by a GPS module; for that you need the documentation. Same goes for interpreting the proprietary `GPACCURACY`.

Comment: The talker ID is GP, ex `$GPRMC`

Comment: If that is the case correct the question rather then adding a comment, or just omit the `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 868 manual:
    Message ID GPACCURACY:ACCURACY OF THE LOCATION 
This message is accuracy of the location; The smaller the number is, the be better the condition is;
Table 2-11: GPACCURACY Data Format
Example: $GPACCURACY,961.2*04

Link to manual:
http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM868/SIM868_NMEA%20Message%20Specification_V1.03.pdf